# LoginName does not display and Loginstatus automatically change to Login after user login (Asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, loginstatus

I have created 3 folders to manage users in ASP.NET and i also created 3 roles by the name of officer, user and admin.now based on the following code user can redirect to specific page, but now the problem is that  i can't see the  username after login which were added using **loginName**  and **LoginStatus** automatically  change from logout to login. it seems that user did not log in and asking  to log in again. (funny problem.....)

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
    {
        //Perform setting cookie information

        e.Authenticated = true;
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "r_admin"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("admin/default.aspx");
        }

        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "r_officer"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/officer/default.aspx");
        }
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "r_user"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/user/default.aspx");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you using Sitemap? If so, can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the Response.Redirect instructions to the LoggedIn event, instead of the Authenticate event.

on your login control add the Loggedin event like this:

```
  <asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" OnLoggedIn="Login1_OnLoggedIn"></asp:Login>
```

and in the code behind:

```
protecetd void Login1_OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "r_admin"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("admin/default.aspx");
    }

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "r_officer"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/officer/default.aspx");
    }
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "r_user"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/user/default.aspx");
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx

Comment: please explain more i could not understant, should i add new method LoggedIn enent?